# Numbering rows in SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis

I have a table like the following in an Access DB:

Worksheet1 -- Line1
Worksheet1 -- Line2
Worksheet2 -- Line1
Worksheet2 -- Line2

Now, there is some bad data, and sometimes you get two of the same line numbers with the same worksheet ID. I'm going to be using SSIS to pull this data into an SQL server db with tighter constraints, and so I need a way to transform the LineID row to avoid this duplication. Is there any way I can accomplish this in SSIS?

Comment: The combination of Worksheet and Line number should be unique in the data flow, correct? What action should be taken if there are duplicates? Kick both out as invalid, pick one (arbitrary or rule based selection), roll data together (what are the survivorship rules?)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

```
select distinct Column1, Column2
from YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server, I'd recommend using the [row_number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) function in your source query. With access, I believe you'll have to do this in the data flow.

It can be done with a script component, but this will require a basic understanding of vb.net or c#.

Konesans has a free Row Number Transformation located at http://www.konesans.com/products/row-number-transformation.aspx

It's basically a data flow task that will add a row number to your data flow.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Aggregate control flow item you group you data before importing.

http://munishbansal.wordpress.com/2010/04/21/how-to-remove-duplicate-records-from-flat-file-source-ssis/